# Data mysteriously disappear from sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

we have database on SQL Server 2008 R2 and data in one table mysteriously disappear from time to time. Data are inserted through web application calling stored procedure in database. After the user enters data and save them he has to print those data because of business logic. But like I said before sometimes data disappear from table which has 20 column; one column (lets call it id_column) is PK and has identity(1,1) property on. After checking data in table we noticed gaps between id_column values, for example: 100, 101, 102, 103, 106...so 104 and 105 were missing. On those id-s should be data that are missing and we know they were there because we have printed report. We set up instead of delete trigger on this table but deleted rows wasn't captured. Also we restored log backups from the time when that happened but in log files were no delete actions. Can you please help and explain how they disappear and how to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the DB mirrored or replicated ? And if yes, what type ?

Comment: No, neither mirrored or replicated...

Comment: What does the on delete trigger do?

Comment: @DanBracuk Trigger just copy deleted data into another table...

Comment: do you have any scheduled jobs messing with the data, or maybe a disgruntled employee ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk nope, no jobs hitting this table...and disgruntled employee hopefully not

Comment: When you restored the backups, were the rows present in the table? Are you sure that someone or some process is not somehow updating this value? Also, a Trigger can be disabled, even if that is unlikely to be happening. Have you tested the `INSTEAD OF DELETE` Trigger to make sure that it is working as expected?

Comment: Is your web app guarded against [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks? This may not be likely, but OTOH it is a possibility...

Comment: `IDENTITY` columns may contain gaps in the sequence. You shouldn't *care* about this or the numerical values. If you do care, you're misusing them.

Comment: @srutzky yes, we tested instead of delete trigger and it's working as expected and it's enabled all the time but no deletion were captured. After we did the restore there were no rows in the table. And if deletion happened log should be recorded in DB Log but there is no such actions in log and that is strange...

Comment: One way to prevent this, but it isn't beautiful (instead you should get rid of the source of the problem). Setup a second table with the exact same structure. Create a (non-cascading) foreign key to link the tables. Create a TRIGGER to insert an exact copy of the row in the second table. Deletes in the source table should then simply fail.

Comment: Ok, so if the Trigger has been tested and found to be working, and is enabled, and the rows are _not_ in the restored table, then last question should be: how is the report that has been printed and shows these "missing" values being generated? Is it using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` table hint, or using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED`? Either of those could explain this behavior.

Comment: @srutzky sorry but table hint NOLOCK or ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED aren't used...

Answer (score 3):

You will have gaps in the IDs if the transaction is started but then rolled back.
If the delete trigger is not firing and you don't see a delete in the transaction log, I'll say a delete never happened.  But a rollback could.

Comment: Yes, this is logical...we are using in stored procedure for saving data try...catch and if something went wrong with insert, transaction rollback...but in this case data won't be saved into table and we have printed evidence that they were there..or something else rollback transaction? Any idea who and how?

Comment: Actually data will be saved into table (at least looking from the same connection) and if you have your printing done from same database connection while transaction is active, but not commited, then your scenario is quite possible.

Comment: @Arvo well, you're right...and how to prevent this?

Comment: @Arvo That is not necessarily true. The data cannot be inserted and selected in the same transaction unless there is an explicit transaction and these are different steps and something after the SELECT does a rollback. Highly unlikely. The only thing that can explain missing rows but showing on a report is doing dirty reads via NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.

Comment: @srutzky Correct, I forgot reporting with NOLOCK hint - this is even more likely than my scenario with explicit transaction. BTW, I have seen such explicit transaction thing in our desktop software (which uses same SQL connection from start to end) - one buggy script started transaction, but didn't end it; all this looked kinda cool - I created new documents, printed these, closed app, started it again - no trace of said documents, neither in SQL or in our app. IDs were increased of course.